# Removing duplicates from result of multiple join on tables with different columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct, combinations

I am trying to make one statement to pull data from 3 related tables (as in they all share a common string index).  I am having trouble preventing MySQL from returning the product of two of the tables, making the result set much larger than I want it.  Each table has a different number of columns, and I would prefer to not use UNION anyway, because the data in each table is separate.

Here is an example:

Table X is the main table and has fields A B.

Table Y has fields A C D.

Table Z has fields A E F G.

-

My ideal result would have the form:

```
A1 B1 C1 D1 E1 F1 G1

A1 B2 C2 D2 00 00 00

A2 B3 C3 D3 E2 F2 G2

A2 B4 00 00 E3 F3 G3
```

etc...

-

Here is the simplest SQL I have tried that shows my problem (that is, it returns the product of Y * Z indexed by data from A:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *

FROM X

LEFT JOIN Y USING (A)

LEFT JOIN Z USING (A)
```

-

I have tried adding a group by clause to fields on Y and Z.  But, if I only group by one column, it only returns the first result matched with each unique value in that column (ie: A1 C1 E1, A1 C2 E1, A1 C3 E1).  And if I group by two columns it returns the product of the two tables again.

I've also tried doing multiple select statements in the query, then joining the resulting tables, but I received the product of the tables as output again.

Basically I want to merge the results of three select statements into a single result, without it giving me all combinations of the data.  If I need to, I can resort to doing multiple queries.  However, since they all contain a common index, I feel there should be a way to do it in one query that I am missing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, maybe this will make it easier to understand my problem.  Just ignore table X and try to join table Y and Z on field A. IE: SELECT *
FROM Y INNER JOIN Z USING (A).  You will see that this outputs the product of the two tables.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand your problem, but why are you using a LEFT JOIN? The story sounds more like an INNER JOIN. Nothing here calls for a UNION.

[Edit]
OK, I think I see what you want now. I've never tried what I am about to suggest, and what's more, some DBs don't support it (yet), but I think you want a windowing function.

```
WITH Y2 AS (SELECT Y.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS YROW FROM Y),
     Z2 AS (SELECT Z.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS ZROW FROM Z)
SELECT COALESCE(Y2.A,Z2.A) AS A, Y2.C, Y2.D, Z2.E, Z2.F, Z2.G
FROM Y2 FULL OUTER JOIN Z2 ON Y2.A=Z2.A AND YROW=ZROW;
```

The idea is to print the list in as few rows as possible, right? So if A1 has 10 entries in Y and 7 in Z, then we get 10 rows with 3 having NULLs for the Z fields. This works in Postgres. I do not believe this syntax is available in MySQL.

Y:

```
 a | d | c  
---+---+----
 1 | 1 | -1
 1 | 2 | -1
 2 | 0 | -1
```

Z:

```
 a | f | g | e 
---+---+---+---
 1 | 9 | 9 | 0
 2 | 1 | 1 | 0
 3 | 0 | 1 | 0
```

Output of statement above:

```
 a | c  | d | e | f | g 
---+----+---+---+---+---
 1 | -1 | 1 | 0 | 9 | 9
 1 | -1 | 2 |   |   |  
 2 | -1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1
 3 |    |   | 0 | 0 | 1
```

Comment: I've tried it with both inner join and left join;  both ways results in the product of y and z.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Andrew.  I just about switched over to PostgreSQL.  But I was able to get a 'good enough' result in MySQL by just adding another field to the on clause.  SELECT Y.*, Z.* FROM Y LEFT OUTER JOIN Z USING (A, id) UNION DISTINCT SELECT Y.*, Z.* FROM Y RIGHT OUTER JOIN Z USING (A, id).

Comment: Additionally, I found out how to add row numbers to queries in MySQL.  This is what led me to the idea to just use the id field, and accept slightly disjointed rows.  At least it returns each row only 1 time.  SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum, Y.* FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS rownum, Y;

Answer (score 0):

Yep, `UNION` is not the answer.

I'm thinking you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
    JOIN y ON x.a = y.a
    JOIN z ON x.a = z.a
GROUB BY x.a;
```

Comment: This is wrong because there might be multiple records in y and z that need to be retrieved for each one in x.  If I group by x.a I only get the first row from each table.  If I take out the group by part, I get the product of y and z.

Answer (score 0):

I found a new way editing this post and this can be used to merg two table 
according to unique ids.
Try this:

```
create table y
(
a int,
d int,
c int
)

create table z
(
a int,
f int,
g int,
e int
)

go

insert into y values(1,1,-1)
insert into y values(1,2,-1)
insert into y values(2,0,-1)

insert into z values(1,9,9,0)
insert into z values(2,1,1,0)
insert into z values(3,0,1,0)

go

select * from y
select * from z

WITH Y2 AS (SELECT Y.*, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY A) AS YROW FROM Y where A = 3),
     Z2 AS (SELECT Z.*, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER (ORDER BY A) AS ZROW FROM Z where A = 3)
SELECT COALESCE(Y2.A,Z2.A) AS A, Y2.C, Y2.D, Z2.E, Z2.F, Z2.G
FROM Y2 FULL OUTER JOIN Z2 ON Y2.A=Z2.A AND YROW=ZROW;
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is always the right answer to most MySQL issues, but your problem could have been solved this way :

The issue you experienced was that you had two left joins, i.e.

A left join X left join Y which inevitably gives you A x X x Y where you wanted (AxX)x(AxY)

A simple solution could be :

```
select x.A,x.B,x.C,x.D,y.E,y.F,y.G from (SELECT A.A,A.B,X.C,X.D FROM A LEFT JOIN X ON A.A=X.A) x INNER JOIN (SELECT A.A,Y.E,Y.F,Y.G FROM A LEFT JOIN Y ON A.A=Y.A) y ON x.A=y.A
```

For the test details :

```
CREATE TABLE A (A varchar(3),B varchar(3));
CREATE TABLE X (A varchar(3),C varchar(3), D varchar(3));
CREATE TABLE Y (A varchar(3),E varchar(3), F varchar(3), G varchar(3));
INSERT INTO A(A,B) VALUES ('A1','B1'), ('A2','B2'), ('A3','B3'), ('A4','B4');
INSERT INTO X(A,C,D) VALUES ('A1','C1','D1'), ('A3','C3','D3'), ('A4','C4','D4');
INSERT INTO Y(A,E,F,G) VALUES ('A1','E1','F1','G1'), ('A2','E2','F2','G2'), ('A4','E4','F4','G4');
select x.A,x.B,x.C,x.D,y.E,y.F,y.G from (SELECT A.A,A.B,X.C,X.D FROM A LEFT JOIN X ON A.A=X.A) x INNER JOIN (SELECT A.A,Y.E,Y.F,Y.G FROM A LEFT JOIN Y ON A.A=Y.A) y ON x.A=y.A
```

As a summary, yes MySQL has many many many issues, but this is not one of them - most of the issues concern more advanced stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, table `X` has a `1:n` relationship with **both** tables `Y` and `Z`. So, the behaviour you see is expected. The result you get is a kind of Cross Product.

If `X` has Person data, `Y` has Address data for those persons and `Z` has Phone data for those persons, then it's natural your query to show all combinations of addresses and phones for every person. If someone has 3 addresses and 4 phones in your tables, then the query shows 12 rows in the result.

You could avoid it by either using a `UNION` query or issuing two queries:

```
SELECT X.*
     , Y.*

FROM X
  LEFT JOIN Y 
    ON Y.A = X.A
```

and:

```
SELECT X.*
     , Z.*

FROM X 
  LEFT JOIN Z 
    ON Z.A = X.A
```